# How to pass only part of input value to variable and url?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, preg-replace, str-replace

So on the site i am building i need to extract only part of value from input form field and pass that to variable but i am a bit confused how to do that.

Well i made a code where

```
mysite.com/?getid=620
```

Should return some data from json file with that id.

And this works.

But!

Now the problem is that i need to get that id from url address posted in input field.

The form with input field looks like this

```
        <form name="appids" method="get" action="?">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Insert url from Steam</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="appids" name="appids" value="" placeholder="http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/" >
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Calculate</button>
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

As you can see it's bootstrap and there is already placeholder explaining user what he need to post in input field.

So the visitor just copy and paste url and i need to extract only number from that and pass it into variable or site url.

The user post this

```
http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/
```

And i need only this

```
620
```

What are the ways to do something like this ? Javascript or php code?

EDIT:

There sometime can be some type of code after the number in url, so sometime url can look like this

```
http://store.steampowered.com/app/241280/?snr=1_6_4__421
```

So i have to strip that part too ?snr=1_6_4__421

And i would try to avoid javascript because if user visit with certain mobile javascript might break sometime.

Comment: Do you **only** want to retrieve the string `620` from the string `http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/`?

Comment: Yes i need only 620 from whole url.

Comment: What if URL is like `http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/show/12`? Do you need only the id after `/app/`?

Comment: Yes this might happen also, i updated my question that its possible also to have some code after the id. so i need to strip everything and leave only numbers after /app/.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you can extract app id with jQuery as user types in the field:

```
$('#appids').keyup(function(){
    var match = $.trim(this.value).match(/\/app\/(\d+)\/?$/);
    if (match) {
        console.log(match[1]);
    }
});
```

Or, preg_match can help you in PHP:

```
if (preg_match('@/app/(\d+)/?$@', $_GET['appids'], $match)) {
    echo 'App ID = '.$match[1];
}
```

Comment: i tried this also but seems that i can't get it to work it doesn't post anything at all from the form when i use this code.

Answer (score 1):

### In Javascript:

```
var num = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/".replace(/.+?(\d+)(\/)?$/,"$1");
```

### In PHP:

I don't know PHP but you can use the regex `/.+?(\d+)(\/)?$/` and replace it with `$1`

Answer (score 1):

> Why are you not using session variable for storing a variable valus?
>   try this`

```
    <?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['views']=1;
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
//retrieve session data
echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete lack of validation and trailing slash notwithstanding:

**Javascript variant**:

```
var url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/".split("/"),
    num = url[url.length - 2];
```

**PHP variant**:

```
$url = split("/", "http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/");
$num = $url[count($url) - 2];
```

Answer (score 1):

A normal submission would do just fine: [**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GIFf79)

```
<?php
// try in your form
// http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/
// http://store.steampowered.com/app/241280/?snr=1_6_4__421

if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $url = $_GET['appids'];
    $url = strtok($url, '?');
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $pieces = array_filter(explode('/', $path));
    $id = end($pieces);
    echo $id;
}

?>

<form method="GET" name="appids">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Insert url from Steam</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="appids" name="appids" value="" placeholder="http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/" >
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But i still get this in url when i submit form mysite.com/?appids=http%3A%2F%2Fstore.steampowered.com%2Fapp%2F4000%2F

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević you sure man? check out my edit and I made a demo

Comment: Yes im sure, it post whole code from input into url. Maybe you didn't understood my question. Here's link to what i am trying to say [Image](http://postimg.org/image/cdg7f0p6r/) in image your code works fine when getting data and shrink it only to numbers. But input pass whole code into website url address. Check the image and see what i am talking about. Sorry if i don't explain things clearly.